# How to show correct "umlaute" with javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle, encoding, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex and the whole application is set to utf-8, therefore i have no problems with "ä,ö,ü". But I changed the appearance of some items using javascript and now f.e. the umlaut "ü" looks like this `&#xFC;`.

How do i change the charset for these items back to utf-8 or find a way to show the "umlaute" correctly.

Thanks alot

Comment: I think the key question here is what is the Javascript you are using to change the "appearance" of some items? That shouldn't happen and I don't think I've ever seen it happen before.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ü, ü     \u00dc, \u00fc
// Ä, ä     \u00c4, \u00e4
// Ö, ö     \u00d6, \u00f6
// ß        \u00df
```

I would say – do not waste time, use Unicode syntax which will always resolve to the characters you want to show in your strings.

For example:

```
var a = '\u00d6\u00df'; // will be displayed as Öß
```

Comment: The data that is shown in APEX is from a database. Therefore i would have to change all data by hand to unicode which would take to much time . Is there a solution that uses unicode where I don't have to change all data by hand? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Jackless,

Please go to item, Security & set Escape special characters to No

I think solve your problem.